# Clear the content of NSMutableString instance

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablestring

I created an `NSMutableString` pointer variable and appended some text using the below code in the implementation file.

```
NSMutableString *displayString;
[displayString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", digit]];
```

However, I would like to clear the `displayString` contents and would like append new text.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Don't forget to allocate/initialize your string instance.

Comment: Allocation/initialization was done already.

Comment: but not in the snippet above it wasnt

Answer (score 7):

Setting the string to an empty string should do the trick, and allow you to append to it again.

```
[displayString setString:@""]
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set its string to empty string.
In this case, it will be like

```
displayString.string = @""
```